# JdbcTemplate undertanding

Tags: spring, jdbc, database-connection, datasource, connection-pooling

Here's something that I am running across as of late.

My understanding of Spring's JdbcTemplate is that you can call:

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
Connection conn = template.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

Which returns you a connection from the JdbcTemplate using the datasource that is passed in.  If I then do:

```
template.getDataSource().getConnection().close();
```

does this just get yet another connection and close it, creating a leaky resource, or does it get you THE connection that it is using?

EDIT:

I have written 2 methods in a class one is the old-school low level way of writing JDBC statements (with Connections, Statements, and ResultSets):

```
public void execute(String tableName) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://viper", "******", "******"); 
        Statement select = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM ******." + tableName );
        logger.info("start clearing: " + tableName);

        while (rs.next ()) {
            rs.deleteRow();
        }
        logger.info("Step1 done clearing: " + tableName);

        ConnectionRecycler.recycleConnection(select, true, con);

        execute2(tableName);
    } catch (Exception eX) {
        logger.error(eX);
    }
}
```

The other method:

```
public void execute2(String tableName) {

    String nameOS = System.getProperty("os.name");
    String sql = (nameOS.equals("OS/400")) ? "DELETE from " + tableName : 
        "DELETE from " + tableName + " with none";

    JdbcTemplate templateSNPJ;

    templateSNPJ = new JdbcTemplate(this.snpjDataSource);
    templateSNPJ.update(sql);

    logger.info("Finished clearing: " + tableName);
    getServiceManager().unregisterService(this);
}
```

I have the resources being cleaned up correctly this way.  The second method, is using a:

```
JdbcTemplate.update(sqlCommand);
```

But it appears that the JdbcTemplate is keeping the connection's alive longer than the pool is configured for.

I read this article on SO:  [Database connection management in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249993/database-connection-management-in-spring) and it eluded to having to use a dataSource configuration with a destroy-method=closed parameter defined in the bean like so:

```
    <bean id="SnpjDataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.nonxa.AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="@#$$datasource"/>
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:as400://VIPER/******"/>
      <property name="user" value="FuManChu"/>
      <property name="password" value="*%$@^%$*#^$@^$@"/>
      <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
      <property name="reapTimeout" value="40"/>
    </bean>
```

EDIT2:

The ConnectionRecycler.recycleConnection method:

```
public static void recycleConnection(Statement state, boolean closeConnection, 
        Connection connect) {
    try {
        state.close();
        if (closeConnection) {
            connect.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        logger.error("Error closing resources!  ", sqlEx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your datasource. If you want to be certain to use the same Connection, either keep a handle on it from the `#getConnection` call or use a [SingleConnectionDataSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SingleConnectionDataSource.html). Note that you have to be operating in a thread-safe env to use this datasource. It itself isn't thread-safe.

Also, you shouldn't really need to access the `Connection` directly. That's the whole point of `JdbcTemplate`. It hides the JDBC internals... avoids risk of leaking Connections, etc.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need access to the Connection?

Comment: @wmorricon365 I added a lot more information at the top.  I was debating on putting it in there the first time around.  Spring supposedly managed the closing of the resources in the backend, but it is appearing that it is not cleaning up the resources.  My connection pool is running out of connections.  This class is the only thing running in a timer thread.  I have also narrowed it down to the JdbcTemplate being the leak.  If you look at my ConnectionRecycler.recycleConnection() method it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Hi Josh. I've noted you're using an `AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean` and have pooled Connections. I was wondering if you knew how this DS provided Connections and recycled them. Does its `#close` actually close the connection or re-add it to the pool. How many iterations are you doing before you see the fail and does it exceed the `com.atomikos.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool#borrowConnectionTimeout`? i.e. Is the Connection available for reuse? Also, have you tried using an alternative datasource in your testing (to isolate the issue to JDBCTemplate, the DS or your config?

Comment: actually I am in the process of researching that one now.  This system was purchased from an IBM subsidiary called Genelco (which is for life insurance) and was ran through some code converter from RPG to Java.

Comment: Sorry got pulled away from my desk:  Here's the edit - actually I am in the process of researching that one now.  This system was purchased from an IBM subsidiary called Genelco (which is for life insurance) and was ran through some code converter from RPG to Java.  To answer your question, the iterations were pretty simple. If I set my pool to 20 connections (in the above xml config) remove the call to ConnectionRecycler, and set the reapTimeout to 0, I can run the service exactly 10 times before I empty the connectionPool. The next thing is to test an alternative DataSource perhaps.

Comment: The only thing the Atomikos API mentions about the close is - " doClose - protected abstract void doClose()"    http://www.atomikos.com/downloads/transactions-essentials/com/atomikos/AtomikosTransactionsEssentials/javadoc/3.7/com/atomikos/jdbc/nonxa/AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean.html

Comment: Hi Josh, I think it's be sensible to try it with another DHCP connection pool. Also, there may be fine logging that indicate what's happening under the hood in the pool and connection (e.g. "returned to pool"). It seems strange that you have 20 connections but they're exhausted after 10 iterations.

Comment: I agree, I swapped out to the BasicDataSouce for connection pooling, but this Genelco software is so tightly tied to Atomikos that it was a nightmare.  I did however try writing a low level JDBC setup(get a connection from the AtomikosPool, create a statement, execute a query, then close resources) that is already setup.  Interesting enough when I explicitly call conn.close(), it's not closing it.  I built a check into place that outputs whether or not the connection is closed, and it comes back false each time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28813/discussion-between-wmorrison365-and-josh-gooding)