# Does Spring automatically close DataSource and is closing needed?

Tags: java, spring

I am setting up a connection pool as a bean in Spring like millions of applications.

Due to transaction management, when the app shuts down, all connections would be returned to the pool. The pool would then be dereferenced and/or the JVM would then shutdown.

So, is it still necessary to close the connection pool? Does Spring automatically do so for `DataSource`s?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249993/database-connection-management-in-spring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database connection management in Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249993/database-connection-management-in-spring)

Answer (score 1):

You generally do not close a DataSource - you just close the connection returned by a DataSource. The DataSource itself is never "open" as such.

One easiest way the connection pool closing taken care by itself is - 
when the app shutsdown, the context unloads, by defining destroy-method = "close" in the connection pool bean, It shutsdown the connections.

Example

```
<bean class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
```

Comment: I am not sure the 1st paragraph applies to a connection pool. The pool would obviously hold open connections.While the pool would eventually be garbage collected, I do wonder if any resource needs to be released explicitly via close.

Comment: @billc.cn It does apply, DataSource is pooled